# Returning value from a google maps callback function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous

Hi I am working with google maps API
I have this huge code, so I dont want to scare away people with code
Basically this is what I need to do

I have a javascript(1) function that I call from Html after someone clicks a button,
from that function I do some processing to calculate the latitudes and longitudes and call a custom function which uses the latitudes and longitudes and calls a google maps function. I need to pass that the value from the google maps call back function back to the javascript function (1)

here is how it goes

--------------File First.html----------------

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function docalculation
{
  .....some calculations for latlng......
  var value = get_value(latlng);
}
</script>
<html>
  .....html file....
  <input type="button" value="Create Directions" onClick="docalculation()">
</html>
```

-------------------file functions.js----------------

```
var return_val;
function get_val(latlng)
{
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {

  return_val = (results[0].address_components[i].long_name);
  alert(return_val); //here I get the value that I need in alert
  }

alert (return_val); // here the value suddenly becomes undefined
return val; // hence returns undefined
}
```

Please help I am stuck here and could not find a solution even after 2 days of googling and trying everything I know.

any help appreciated thanks

The simplest solution that I am looking for would be some way to store the value of return_val into variable value

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a variable scope problem, but without the full frame of reference it will be a little difficult to figure out where it is going off the rails.

Comment: Is there any way I can store this value (return_val) ..... I need the solution desperately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `geocode()` is asynchronous: it returns immediately but the callback function is invoked as soon as the response arrives. You need to accept a callback in `get_val()` and pass the value to this method instead of trying to return it (it's impossible):

```
function get_val(latlng, cb) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': latlng
    }, function (results, status) {
        cb(results[0].address_components[i].long_name);
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
get_value(latlng, function(longName) {
    /* do something */
});
```

Comment: I bet questions about return value and asynchronous functions are one of the most common JavaScript questions here

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there is one more problem that I would face using this solution ........

what the function returns is the name of the road......

what I need to do is store the first value in variable say first road and store the second value in variable say second road and compare the vars first road and second road to see if they have same value and I need to do this in a loop several times.... thanks for the quick reply though ...

Comment: @ThiefMaster, your usage should be `get_value( latlng, function(longName) { /*do something*/}`

Comment: @ThiefMaster could u suggest something else please

Comment: @Nick: You can pass multiple arguments to the callback function

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could use ThiefMaster's answer to get multiple longitudes in one call. Not for the faint of heart.

```
/**
 * @param {string[]} values longitude strings
 * @param cb {function} The callback that will be passed a 
 *        map keyed by latlng strings where each value
 *        is the long name of the street
 */
function getLongNames(values, cb) {
    var returnValues = {};
    var responseCount = 0;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    for (var i =0; i < values.length; i++) {
        getSingleName(values[i], function(latLng, longName) {
            returnValues[latLng] = longName;
            responseCount++;
            if (responseCount == values.length) {
                cb(returnValues);
            }
        });
    }

    function getSingleName(latlng, cb) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'latLng': latlng
        }, function (results, status) {
            cb(latlng, results[0].address_components[i].long_name);
        });
    }
}
```

And you call it like this

```
// The callback is the code that is run once all the latLng have been processed
getLongNames(["latLng1", "latLng2","latLng2"], function (valueMap) {
  for (var latLng in valueMap) {
    console.log("Latitude Longitude:" + latLng + " Long Name " + valueMap[latLng]);
  }
});
```

Comment: HI Juan thanks for the reply .... your code helps in a way that I can compare both the roads in a function, but, after comparing them too, I need to pass a boolean to determine whether the values match or not, and I dont think we can achieve that after using this code..........

Comment: @Nick: I don't understand what you mean. You have all the values in the returned map. What is it you can't compare? Show your code and what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @Juam Mendes : According to me the simplest solution that I am looking for this problem is some way of extracting the value of variable return_val that I mentioned in the original code, and store it in some variable in docalculation function (in original question)...... is there anyway I can achieve that...... I really appreciate your effort .... please help me with this evil problem if you can thanks

Comment: @Nick: According to you, you are wrong :) There is no way to call the function and have it return the value, that's the nature of asynchronous calls. Return values are passed through the callback function. You need to adjust your code and thinking to use callbacks. We've given you lots of clues about how to do it.

Comment: @Juan Mendes I this means I have to scrap my whole project .... if there is no way I can achive this ..... because the nature of the problem that I am working on requires that I store the value....

Comment: @Nick: you didn't even show an attempt at what we showed you. I'm sure that's not true, just change the structure of how you have to call this function, every JavaScript developer has to use this pattern at some point.

Comment: @Juan Mendes Hey! Thanks for the concern, but, I did try it and the logic of my program does'nt allow me to do this...I tried all different approaches and only after exhausting my brain, I posted here...let me tell you what I am supposed to do...I am supposed to take a google directions object and break it into pieces in such a way that each piece contains a journey only on a single road and and return the start and end point of each piece and finally pass the array or JSOn of these points to another function...really thanks for your help though...If you come up with something just let me know

Comment: oh! i need to return start and end points of the road and also the name of the road

Comment: @Nick: sorry you don't understand what we're telling you. But you're still thinking the wrong way, you *CANNOT* create a function that returns values that are retrieved asynchronously. The values must be retrieved from the callback. If you update your answer by adding the code that has the functions that need to call each other, I could provide you more guidance.

Comment: @Juan Mendes Okay I will work out a new algo and used the method mentioned by you and post it here as soon as I can